plugin:vite:react-babel /Users/patrick/Desktop/TELEGRAM/src/App.tsx: Unterminated JSX contents. (34:10)
i am new to this can someone tell me where the error in this code is ? i cant find it:
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(29857775);
  const [energy, setEnergy] = useState(2532);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient-main min-h-screen px-4 flex flex-col items-center text-white font-medium">

      <div className="absolute inset-0 h-1/2 bg-gradient-overlay z-0"></div>
      <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-0">
      <div className="radial-gradient-overlay"></div>

      <div className="w-full z-10 min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center text-white">

        <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full px-4 pt-8 z-10 flex flex-col items-center text-white">
          <div className="w-full cursor-pointer">
            <div className="bg-[#1f1f1f] text-center py-2 rounded-xl">
              <p className="text-lg">Join CHEEMSCAT <Arrow size={18} className="ml-0 mb-1 inline-block" /></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div className="mt-12 text-5xl font-bold flex items-center">
          <img src={coin} width={44} height={44} />
          <span className="ml-2">{points.toLocaleString()}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="text-base mt-2 flex items-center">
          <img src={trophy} with={24} height={24} />
          <span className="ml-1">Gold <Arrow size={18} className="ml-0 mb-1 inline-block"/>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App

it points to row 34 in visual studio code
i tried to close everything but i cant find what is wrong any help would be rally appreciated, thanks

In your JSX their are no enclosing  tags for first and third  tags.
